# Identity Server 4 running within docker container Exception: Unable to load DLL 'System.Security.Cryptography.Native.OpenSsl'

Tags: c#, docker, asp.net-core, identityserver4, .net-core

I am trying to get Identity Server 4 running with ASP.NET Core in a docker container and I keep on getting the following exception

```
Unhandled Exception: System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'Crypto' threw an exception. ---> System.DllNotFoundException: Unable to load DLL 'System.Security.Cryptography.Native.OpenSsl': The specified module could not be found.
 (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)
   at Interop.Crypto.GetMaxMdSize()
   at Interop.Crypto..cctor()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Interop.Crypto.GetRandomBytes(Byte[] buf, Int32 num)
   at System.Security.Cryptography.RNGCryptoServiceProvider.GetBytes(Byte[] data)
   at IdentityModel.CryptoRandom.CreateUniqueId(Int32 length)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.IdentityServerBuilderExtensions.SetTemporarySigningCredential(IIdentityServerBuilder builder)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.IdentityServerServiceCollectionExtensions.AddDeveloperIdentityServer(IServiceCollection services)
   at Identity.Startup.ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj, Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.ConfigureServicesBuilder.Invoke(Object instance, IServiceCollection exportServices)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost.EnsureApplicationServices()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost.BuildApplication()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.WebHostBuilder.Build()
   at Identity.Program.Main(String[] args)
```

DockerFile

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:latest
WORKDIR /app
ENV ASPNETCORE_URLS http://*:80
EXPOSE 80
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "Identity.dll"]
COPY . /app
```

Project.json

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
      "version": "1.0.1",
      "type": "platform"
    },
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc": "1.0.1",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing": "1.0.1",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.1",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileExtensions": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.CommandLine": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Http.Abstractions": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "CassandraCSharpDriver": "3.1.0-beta1",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink.Loader": "14.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cors": "1.1.0-preview1-final",

    "Core.Data.Cassandra": "0.1.0",
    "IdentityServer4": "1.0.0-rc2"
  },

  "tools": {
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final"
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "netcoreapp1.0": {
      "imports": [
        "dotnet5.6",
        "portable-net45+win8"
      ]
    }
  },

  "buildOptions": {
    "emitEntryPoint": true,
    "preserveCompilationContext": true
  },

  "runtimeOptions": {
    "configProperties": {
      "System.GC.Server": true
    }
  },

  "publishOptions": {
    "include": [
      "wwwroot",
      "**/*.cshtml",
      "appsettings.json",
      "web.config",
      "Dockerfile.debug",
      "Dockerfile",
      "docker-compose.debug.yml",
      "docker-compose.yml"
    ]
  },

  "scripts": {
    "postpublish": [ "dotnet publish-iis --publish-folder %publish:OutputPath% --framework %publish:FullTargetFramework%" ]
  },

  "tooling": {
    "defaultNamespace": "Identity"
  }
}
```

Comment: full .NET Framework / Mono target or .NET Core? If Mono, make sure your docker image is based on an image which has mono 4.6 installed

Comment: I'm using the Microsoft/dotnet core image which i believe uses .NET Core

Comment: Added whole project.json for reference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this is because you're mixing 1.0.x, 1.1.0 packages and 1.0.0 runtime. Either use 1.0.x or 1.1.0 everywhere (and target netcoreapp1.0 or netcoreapp1.1 accordingly). Related issue on github: https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/12517

Comment: How can I determine which package version goes with which .net version? i'm using Visual Studio code on a mac

Comment: You even have 1.0.0-rc-final LOL. If you want to target 1.1.0: Move all your packages in dependencies (including Microsoft.NetCore.App) but browser link to 1.1.0-preview. Browser link shoould be: 14.1.0-preview1-final. Target netcoreapp1.1. packages in tools should be: 1.0.0-preview3-final. In general I think where there is a major/minor release all versions are inline. For patch releases there packages may differ by patch version.

Comment: Sorry the above instructions are not clear for example 1.0.0-rc-final is not referenced in the project.json above

Comment: I can see this: "Microsoft.AspNet.Http.Abstractions": "1.0.0-rc1-final",